# Can foldr be used as MapReduce?

Tags: haskell, mapreduce, theory

I was thinking that when you do a MapReduce you are transforming your datalist and then using a reduce function to do whatever you want with the transformed data. I guess I can do the same with `foldr`. When doing something like `foldr (filterfun . mapfun) []`. Can I say that Haskell's foldr is identical to a mapreduce? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That would be a bit of a simplifying statement - but sort of yes. The main difference you are probably interested in is that `foldr` folds starting at one end, while MapReduce generally reduces in any order. A better comparison would be with `foldMap`.

Comment: As a side note, unless you have a more specific actual question about this, I'm think this question should be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not quite. As Alec's comment indicates, `foldr` doesn't allow reduction to be reordered or parallelized. For example, if you have

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

then that's

```
1 + (2 + (3 + 4))
```

The implementation of `foldr` can't split the container and sum each half separately, because you're just giving it a function `a -> b -> b` and a value `b`. It can't do anything with the function except apply it to both an element and an accumulator.

```
foldMap :: (Foldable f, Monoid m)
        => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

on the other hand, is very much a `mapReduce`. Since the `Monoid` constraint carries with it a claim of associativity, you can write a `foldMap` that reduces the first half of the container and the second half in parallel, and then mashes them together with `<>`.

---

The default implementation of `foldr` (in `Data.Foldable`) actually uses `foldMap`:

```
foldr c n xs = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . c) xs) n
```

That is, it turns each element into a *function*; those functions are all composed (composition forms a monoid with `id` as its identity) and the result applied to the seed. You can't, however, do anything useful with the intermediate functions!